# Keyboard stops working after using Python Keyboard Library

Tags: python, keyboard

I made a script that utilizes the keyboard library in Python. I only have the following lines that utilize this library.

```
keyboard.wait('alt')
keyboard.write('some string', delay=0.01)
```

The script works but after running it my keyboard stops working after. I am unable to find any other resources about this problem mainly because the library shares the same name as the device that is having problems.

Removing the write line fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working without the line

```
keyboard.write('some string', delay=0.01)
```

because you are waiting for alt key to be pressed

the above line is stopping your program instead of keyboard.wait.
Try to wrap it in a loop

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, what do you mean by the write line skips the alt end?